# SQL trigger to insert row

Tags: sql, split, triggers, payment

I need your help. I have two tables `Payments` and `Invoices`.

I need a trigger that when I insert a payment line automatically associates the payment to the invoice starting from the invoice with the oldest date up to the newest one. Example:

I have 2 Invoices. The first invoice with an amount of € 100.00 and with date 01 May 2018 the second invoice with an amount of € 200.00 with date 1 June 2018.
I receive a payment of € 250.00.
When I enter this payment in my Payments table I need a trigger that splits the payment in the payments table like this:
€ 100.00 to cover the first invoice that is the one with the oldest date and the remaining € 150.00 on the second invoice. Subsequently the recovered amount must be entered in the "amount_recovered" field in the invoice table.

My other problem is this:
When the amount of the payment is greater than the total sum of the invoice amounts, I would need to enter the extra amount in another field designated as "Collection of Interest" and when the amount of the payment is higher even than the sum of the amounts of the bills plus the amount of interest, I would need to associate it with another field named "Expenses".

Example:
I have 2 Invoices. The first invoice with an amount of € 100.00 and with date 01 May 2018 the second invoice with an amount of € 200.00 with date 1 June 2018.
I receive a payment of € 400.00.
Payment should be divided in this way in the payments table:

€ 100.00 to cover the first invoice.
€ 200.00 to cover the second invoice.
€ 50.00 to cover the amount of interest (if the interest amount is € 100.00 all remaining € 100.00 will cover the interest).
€ 50.00 to cover expenses.

The pay table should contain the following lines after upload:

```
Id_Payment | Type_Payment | Mod_Payment | PAYMENT_AMOUNT
1          | Invoice      | CreditCard  | € 100.00
1          | Invoice      | CreditCard  | € 200.00
1          | Interests    | CreditCard  | € 50.00
1          | expenses     | CreditCard  | € 50.00
```

And the invoice table should look like this:

```
Id_Invoices | Invoice_Date | Amount_Invoice | Recovered Amount
1           | 1 May 2018   | € 100.00       | € 100.00
1           | 1 June 2018  | € 200.00       | € 200.00
```

if my question is too complicated and building the trigger takes a long time I could also pay.

Thanks a lot to everyone,
Andrew

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Many products have their own, non-ANSI, versions of triggers.)

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current code attempt.

Comment: Hi all, Now i Haven't any code. I ask your help to develop this trigger.